# Need some help setting up Apache user directories

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server

I would like to have Apache serve "normal" files out of `/srv/http/public`, and user files out of `/srv/http/[user]`, so the directories might look like

```
/srv/http
  /public
    index.html - Accessible at localhost/index.html
  /austin
    index.html - Accessible at localhost/~austin/index.html
```

Right now, I have the following relevant configurations in the Apache `.conf` files

```
User http
Group http
DocumentRoot "/srv/http/public"

<Directory "/srv/http/public">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

UserDir /srv/http
UserDir disabled root

<Directory "/srv/http">
  AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
  Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
  <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Limit>
  <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
  </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

And the following permissions in `/srv/http`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  root    http   /srv/http
drwxr-xr-x  http    http   /srv/http/public
-rwxr-xr-x  http    http   /srv/http/public/index.html
drwxr-xr-x  austin  http   /srv/http/austin
-rwxr-xr-x  austin  http   /srv/http/austin/index.html
```

Using this setup, `localhost/index.html` displays fine, but `localhost/~austin/index.html` 
gives a **403 Access forbidden!** error, no matter what I try.

**Edit:** the relevant error_log entry:  `[error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /srv/http/austin/index.html`

What am I doing wrong?

Oh, and I don't think it really matters, but I'm using Arch Linux, and Apache 2.2.19

Comment: Your logs say...?

Comment: I updated the question with the only message given by the log file (except for the request for the favicon.ico file)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `<Directory>` directive for the user directories was too restrictive.

Re-using the same directives from the `/srv/http/public` directory allows the outside world to see any user files:

```
<Directory "/srv/http">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```